# DataGridTemplateColumns, AutoGenerateColumns=true and binding to a DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm struggling with a confluence of problems.

1. I have a dynamic data set which I manually assemble into a DataTable.
2. I have to auto generate the columns as the data is not static.
3. I need to bind the ItemsSource of a combo box to an Observable collection defined in each cell.

Although I thought it would be easy, the ComboBox cannot see the DataItem in the DataView, rather it tries to bind to the DataView directly.

I've put together a sample project here:

https://github.com/5flags/DataGridBindingIssue

Now, it's obviously contrived to demonstrate the issue. I can't change the data structure at this point, so any solution must be done in the XAML.

To see the problems, use Snoop (or equivalent) to see the binding errors on the ComboBoxes.

The DataGrid is set up like so:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn" CanUserAddRows="False" x:Name="TheDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="dataItemCellTemplate">
            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedOption, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Options}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

And the event handler for the autogeneration is:

```
private void DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
        var col = new DataGridTextColumn {Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName), Header = e.PropertyName};
        e.Column = col;
    }
    else if (e.PropertyType == typeof(DataItem))
    {
        var col = new DataGridTemplateColumn
        {
            CellTemplate = (DataTemplate) TheDataGrid.FindResource("dataItemCellTemplate"),
            CellEditingTemplate = (DataTemplate)TheDataGrid.FindResource("dataItemCellTemplate"),
            Header = e.PropertyName
        };
        e.Column = col;
    }
}
```

The binding error on the combo is:

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Options' property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=22264221)'. BindingExpression:Path=Options; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=22264221); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedOption' property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=22264221)'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedOption; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=22264221); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedValue' (type 'Object')

Comment: Can you please just show your data binding XAML?

Comment: Edited the question to include more info.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have one column named `Options` and one named `SelectedOption` in your `DataTable`?

Comment: The DataItem in the cell has SelectedOption and Options on it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'DataItem'? I thought that you said that you're using a `DataTable`... do you mean `DataRow`? And what makes you think that the `Binding` is reaching the `DataView` instead? What errors do you have in the `Output` window in Visual Studio?

Comment: DataItem is a model class containing a name, a collection of options and a selected option. I've updated the question to show the binding errors.

Comment: Aha! Now I see... try just adding `'DataContext.'` in front of your `Binding.Path` values: `{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedOption, ...}`. This should move from the `DataRowView` to your data item.

Comment: DataRowView doesn't have a DataContext, it's not a WPF object.

Comment: Then perhaps you should use WPF objects? Try adding '`Row.`' in front of your `Binding.Path` values instead then.

Comment: As stated, I cannot change the data side of things, only the WPF side.

Comment: Did you try adding 'Row.' in front of your Binding.Path values instead?

Comment: Yes, DataRow doesn't have properties called Options or SelectedOption.

Comment: I appreciate your time, but perhaps the ready-to-run Github project I created would help?

Comment: I don't have access to Visual Studio now and I'm just about of ideas now too. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dusan's answer set me on the right track. Because I don't know the column names until runtime, I have to create the data template at runtime too. It's actually not difficult.

```
private DataTemplate GetDataTemplate(string columnName)
{
    string xaml = "<DataTemplate><ComboBox SelectedValue=\"{Binding Path=[" + columnName +
                  "].SelectedEnumeratedElementItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}\"" +
                  " ItemsSource=\"{Binding Path=[" + columnName +
                  "].Items}\" DisplayMemberPath=\"Name\"/></DataTemplate>";

    var sr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xaml));
    var pc = new ParserContext();
    pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
    pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
    var datatemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(sr, pc);

    return datatemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify your XAML to:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn" CanUserAddRows="False" x:Name="TheDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="dataItemCellTemplate">
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding [Option].Options}" SelectedValue="{Binding [Option].SelectedOption, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Where `[Option]` refers to the column of `DataView` in which you store your custom `DataItem` objects.

Comment: Thanks, this worked really well in the demo app I created, but in the real app, I don't know the columns until runtime. Your answer put me on the right path though.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know how to do this with `DataTemplate` from `XAML` resources, but it work fine for me with `DataTemplate` created in code.

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTemplateColumn();
    templateColumn.Header = e.PropertyName;

    DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
    FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
    template.VisualTree = factory;
    FrameworkElementFactory childFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
    childFactory.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding(e.PropertyName));
    factory.AppendChild(childFactory);

    templateColumn.CellEditingTemplate = template;

    template = new DataTemplate();
    factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
    template.VisualTree = factory;
    childFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    childFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding(e.PropertyName));
    factory.AppendChild(childFactory);
    templateColumn.CellTemplate = template;

    e.Column = templateColumn;
}
```