# Dynamically generating Row and Column headers for DataGrid using templates WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am working on populating a grid using templates, where I do not know the number of rows and columns, these will be generated via a WCF service in a class that looks something like this:

```
 class GridPoint:
    { 
string Rowheader;
float cellvalue;
     }

class ColumnData: List<GridPoint>
{

}
```

So the datagrid code would be something like this:

```
 MyGrid: DataGrid
{
InitializeComponent();
 private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(objectsender,DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) 
{
 var col = new DataGridTextColumn {Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName), Header = e.PropertyName};
        e.Column = col;

}
}
```

I found a way to auto generate columns with the data template in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493184/datagridtemplatecolumns-autogeneratecolumns-true-and-binding-to-a-datatable) post. However, they have no mention of adding the row header for each point. I would appreciate your help in adding a row header to the mix into the column style.

The end product should look something like this:

```
    Column1   Column2 
Row1    123       123
Row2    811       811 
Row3    123       123
```

A hack I can think of is just generating an extra column with a different style similar to the column header style and adding my row points in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about populating a DataGrid in WPF, unless you set

```
 AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

in your XAML your grid will have it's columns automatically built from the public properties.

The number of rows is not important unless you for some reason need to set a hard limit on the maximum number.

Comment: Since my properties are generated at run-time I have resorted to dynamically choosing the template using these events( a template selector is'nt working as I do not know the Binding names until run-time). Each type of property has its own template. The number of rows isn't important but the Header for each row is. I eventually plan on passing the row and column header value "OnSelected" to a command in my model class.